# How to put escape characters in unicode string on MVC3 model Validation?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, unicode, escaping

I have a dual-language MVC3 application which needs to display errors in Arabic.

I can put the model validation in place as per normal, however for one of my error messages there is an accent character which translates to `"`.

As soon as I try and add an escape character `\` it messes up the string!?

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "خطأ: يجب أن يكون رقم الحساب مكونا" من 13 رقما")]
```

Any idea how to escape this to allow the accent character to be correctly displayed?

Comment: How does it “mess up the string”? Please show what you actually see and where (in which program).

Comment: You can see the effect above with the stackoverflow parser...the `"` in the middle of the string are terminating the LTR string leaving `من 13 رقما` outside the string.

Comment: But you wrote “as soon as I try and add an escape character `\`”. The code posted does not have it, and you have not described what actually happens. “Terminating the string” is something that deduce from some observations. Which? And did you actually put the `\` character *before* the quotation mark? (It should then visually appear on the right of it, if the software used can handle directionality right.)

Comment: OK, lets rephrase:  There is an Arabic accent character that is a " (double quote)...however, if you use this in a string on an MVC3 model validator then the string is INCORRECTLY early-terminated.  If you try and add a \ to escape the string this doesn't work either (I've tried putting it both sides of the ") and the visual parser in VS2010 gets very confused going from a RTL \ to an LTR " and the entire string becomes incorrectly ordered.  SUMMARY: In an LTR language, how do you escape a string delimiting character when your coding language is RTL?

Comment: I don’t see a problem in using `var msg = "خطأ: يجب أن يكون رقم الحساب مكونا\" من 13 رقما";` in JavaScript, so I guess the problem is with VS2010 and you may need a workaround like constructing the string from three pieces (two pieces of text and a string containing just a quotation mark between them). But it might be best to consider whether you really want an Ascii quotation mark `"` inside a string. It should normally not be used in any human language, when written properly. (I can't figure out what it is meant to stand for here.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In an LTR language, how do you escape a string delimiting character when your coding language is RTL?

I can only repeat Jukka's comments: there shouldn't be a problem here. You put the backslash *logically* before the double-quote, which in this case means it appears to the right of it in editors that support bidi text:

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "خطأ: يجب أن يكون رقم الحساب مكونا\" من 13 رقما")]
```

This works fine for me in VS 2010 (although the cursor controls don't match what you might be used to in other apps whilst editing it).

> There is an Arabic accent character that is a " (double quote)

Whilst my knowledge of Arabic is minimal, this seems unlikely. Are you looking for the combining diacritical U+064B Arabic Fathatan? (مكوناً)